# Plesk - Apache / Nginx proxy - Magento 2 - Error: Messy page no style

Tags: apache, magento2, ubuntu-18.04, plesk, nginx-reverse-proxy

I migrated my webshop (Magento 2) to this server with plesk that uses apache and nginx as a proxy. the home page is displayed without style and all messy.

This are the versions that I'm using:

- Plesk: 18.0.32
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5
- Apache: 2.4.29
- Nginx: 1.18.0
- PHP: 7.2.34
- Magento: 2.3.4

These are the errors on the console:

[image]

If I try to navigate to the magento backend page or click any link I see, I get a 500 error.

Can someone help me to solve my problem?